# Looking for another Pro Tem Moderator — Selection complete; welcome, Rory!

Tags: discussion, moderator

### Update:

I am pleased to announced that 'Rory Alsop' has generously agreed to step up to fill the role of a provisional pro tem moderator!

[image: Rory Alsop]

Thank you Rory!

That's not a slight against anyone I was not able to chose in this round of appointments. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and hopefully we'll be able to set up those elections soon.

---

*<original post>*

Our Moderator coverage in general has been a bit light on this site, so I would like to appoint another moderator to assure that we have adequate coverage.

**Are you interested?** I will refer to this thread when making my next appointment. Self-nominations are okay (and encouraged!), but if you know someone who has done a bang-up job in helping folks navigate the nuances of what makes this site "work", I am taking suggestions for folks who interested in actively growing a community.

Leave your suggestion below with a link to their (or your) profile (meta and main site) with a bit of a description of why you feel they would make a good Moderator ♦.
Ideal candidates should:

- Want the responsibility. They should (ideally) be on the site at least every other day, and have at least a few hours each week to tend to flags and whatever issues come up
- Be consistently patient and fair in their dealings with the community
- Be knowledgeable enough about the topic to be able to judge the quality of posts, and identify cleverly crafted spam
- Be ready to lead the community to help you do your jobs. Teach people how to flag properly, encourage a culture of editors and strong reviewers
- Understand and embrace our [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Thank you and to anyone interested… good luck!

Comment: Are the existing moderators spending more time hiking than moderating? ;-)

Comment: @gerrit I hope so!

Comment: Lovely to be here - I hope I will be useful. I already see there is an interesting scope discussion on http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5741/66

Answer (score 15):

At risk of sounding greedy (I mod on a couple of other sites) I'll pop my name down if no-one else steps up.

This is my 5th site by rep, and I'm ranked 4th here on the list of users by reputation. Helping as a pro-tem here until this site can graduate would fit within my available time, and my interests.

I am here almost every day (have visited the site 689 days in the last 27 months, and got my fanatic some time ago), am 3rd or 4th in the review queues, hang out a fair bit on meta (have my convention badge) and generally enjoy dealing with folks fairly and calmly.

Based on my activity record on the other sites I moderate, you can see that I meet each of your 5 requirements, and I am reasonably active on meta.SE, with queries that come up around the 'how this part of SE works' areas.

So far I have helped one of my beta sites through to graduation and beyond - Information Security is now very successful and continuing to grow, with a thriving community, a popular blog site, and key industry professionals recognised as members.

Another site is very close - and the moderators on Music are working with the community on ways to tip us over the edge.

Comment: I think you'd be a great one man. Got my vote!

Answer (score 4):

[Mr Wizard](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/133/mr-wizard) seems a good choice if he's interested?

I know he moderates on Mathematica already so knows the tools, procedures, etc. He's been (in the recent past) active too. Though I've not seen him around for a while.

Comment: I have not been visiting TGO much recently, as you noted.  For that reason I'm probably not a good choice.  Nevertheless I *am* willing to meet the basic requirements of checking in at least every other day and spending a few hours a week on the site, if it is needed.  You can ask the members of [Mathematica.SE] (not [Math.SE] by the way) if I meet the *other* requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Being an Eagle Scout I love the outdoors.  I haven't done any modding for any other stack exchange site... But if moderation is lacking I would be willing to try and help out.

Comment: I would question (politely :) ) whether you have enough experience of using SE sites. TBF I would question wether I have enough experience!!

Comment: No problem whatsoever!  Just wanted to help if there was a need :-D

Answer (score -1):

I guess [Olin Lathrop](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/1854/olin-lathrop) ([Meta Profile](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1854/olin-lathrop)) might be a good choice.

From everything I have read from him he appears to be very thoughtful and seems to have a good feeling about how good Q&A should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, but I'm not a good choice.  I am only on this site sporadically because the activity is so low, and much of what does show up is outside my interest area, like technical climbing.  It seems we have gotten away from general hiking and camping and talk of wild places, at least relative to what it felt like when I first came here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop that's sad!